# Unable to destroy the Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am restricting the user to enter special characters in textbox using jquery.
        i am showing error message to user as bootstrap tooltip.but i am unable to destroy the bootstrap tooltip if the user entered correct data in textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,500,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.teal-red.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var specialKeys = new Array();
            specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
            specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
            specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
            specialKeys.push(36); //Home
            specialKeys.push(35); //End
            specialKeys.push(37); //Left
            specialKeys.push(39); //Right
            specialKeys.push(64);
            var mainelemnt;
            function IsAlphaNumeric(elment, e) {
                mainelemnt = elment;
                var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
                var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || keyCode == 64 || keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 32 || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
                if (ret == false) {
                    $(mainelemnt).tooltip('show');
                } else {
                    $(mainelemnt).tooltip('destroy');
                }
                return ret;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" style="margin-top:100px">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="username"  onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(this, event);"  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="special charecters are not allowed" onblur="ValidateEmail(this)" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Plunker code: https://plnkr.co/edit/L4Hqq15HfQgOGm2R1m80?p=preview.

Comment: who is downvote my question and wt is the reason behind that.

Comment: Not me, but I would guess it's because your question makes little effort to identify the problem area (rather than just linking all code). Explain which line should be removing the tooltip and what you've tried. SO is usually a friendly place, but there are issues where questions deemed to be lacking effort are dealt with with a similar lack of explanation

Comment: hi @AdamHopkinson, when ever user enter special charcters in textbox i am showing error message as bootstrap tooltip, if the user entered corrected data i am removing tooltip,but error is if the user entered wrong data the tooltip is appear it's fine,but after entered correct data ,the tooltip is still showing.please,refer the plunker link.

Comment: hi @AdamHopkinson,please refer the plunker and suggest me.

Comment: @srilu your code works fine. fixed a issue though. here https://plnkr.co/edit/lCXPhUjV9Sb6bDMj6003?p=preview

Comment: hi @WhoAmI,there is no changes applied ,it is same as my plunker,please tell wt changes u done.

Comment: window.event does not exist in FF and always returns undefined. So if you really want to check event exists or not you might use window.event || e;

Comment: hi @WhoAmI,please, done the changes in plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just a littblebit overcomplicated your problem. When a keyup happens, we should not test the character, but the whole string.

And what if somebody paste something with mouse? Now you can assign the on blur yourself...

```
$.fn.isValidAlphaNum = function () {
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test($(this).val());
};

$('#username').keyup(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).isValidAlphaNum()) {
        alert('Not valid');
        //Show the tooltip
    } else {
        alert('Valid');
        //Hide the tooltip
    }
});
```

Here is a working [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sd3canf5/).

Comment: hi, i know this answer, i want to user to be blocked to enter special charcters like my code.

Comment: It is do the same, as you see it happens on keyup. Add it for paste event too. This is check the whole string at every keyup.